# Trouble getting the correct average probability

Tags: probability

Im trying to find the average probability of odds in a given list. I'm unsure what the correct method is

Say the odds are:

```
4/1
3/1
7/2(3.5/1)
2/1
```

Method 1

When I sum up all these odds, I get 12.5 / 4. The average is 3.125. So I work out the average probability to be 1/(1+3.125) = 1/4.125. P =0.24242

Method 2

If I work out the probability on each odds individually and then divide by 4 to get average probability.

```
4/1         P  = 0.2
3/1         P = 0.25
7/2(3.5/1) P = 0.222
2/1         P = 0.333
```

When I add these probabilities up I get 1.005. The average is 1.005/4. P = 0.25125

Which method is the correct way? Im using the average probability to work out the expected gain of the bookmakers.